# TypeError: canvas.width() & canvas.height() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have written a simple jQuery code and I am getting this error:

> TypeError: canvas.width() & canvas.height() is not a function

When declaring variables `w` and `h` it is showing an error of `canvas.width()` and `canvas.height()` is not defined. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
  var w = canvas.width();  
  var h = canvas.height();  
  var cw = 15;  
  var d = "right";  
  var food;  
  var score;  
  var speed = 130;
)};
```

Comment: `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` are not functions

Comment: Please note that asking for help ASAP is [considered rude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var w=canvas.width();  
var h=canvas.height();
```

with

```
var w=canvas.width;  
var h=canvas.height;
```

Example is

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width  = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

Comment: The example seems unrelated as its setting the values, not getting them

Comment: yeah I just wanted to give you an idea. just use var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height; to get width and height.